# How to create a folder the name of multiple files, to move files into that folder, and then rename all of those files

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm using a web crawler to crawl a rather large website with lots of html files, and what it has done is saved the files as (page name).

I want files to be saved as (folder of page name)/index.html, as that is how it is set out on the original website.

The crawler hasn't even saved them as (page name).html, they have no file extension.

I've already crawled most of the site over 2 days so I don't want to re-crawl it.

Does anyone know how I can create a folder name for each of the files, but only the ones without file extensions, as there are some jsons and swfs that shouldn't have a folder.

*and then* move those files into the folders with their name,

***and then*** rename all of the files to index.html?

Is that possible with a cmd command, (or 3, i guess)

I have tried

```
from glob import glob
from os import mkdir
from os.path import join
from shutil import move

files = glob('*')
for file in files:
    if not '.' in file:
        move(file, file+'_tmp')
        mkdir(file)
        move(file+'_tmp', join(file, 'index.html'))
```

in python and

```
for %i in (*) do mkdir "%~ni"
for %i in (*) do move "%i" "%~ni"
```

in cmd

The Python one gave a syntax error and the cmd one created a folder for every file, not just the files with no extension, breaking the other files, and also I couldn't find how to automatically rename them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This in python

from glob import glob
from os import mkdir
from os.path import join
from shutil import move

files = glob('*')
for file in files:
    if not '.' in file:
        move(file, file+'_tmp')
        mkdir(file)
        move(file+'_tmp', join(file, 'index.html'))

Comment: Please don't add code in a comment, because it becomes unreadable. Edit your question and insert the code in there as formatted text.

Comment: I've edited the post now.

Answer (score 0):

`for %i in (*) do...` interprets the wildcard `*` as "all files". Include the dot to make sure to process only files without extension:

on command line:

```
for %a in (*.) do @(ren "%a" "%~na.tmp" && md "%~na" & move "%a.tmp" "%~na\index.html")`
```

as a batch file:

```
for %%a in (*.) do (
  ren "%%a" "%%~na.tmp"
  md "%%~na"
  move "%%a.tmp" "%%~na\index.html"
)
```

Comment: If the file exists without an extension, can a directory be created with the same name?

Comment: @lit: no, it can not... `:/`. Thanks for the hint, answer edited.